# Как выполнять действия по нажатию клавиш ImGui

Tags: c++, directx-11, imgui

Как выполнять действия по нажатию клавиши, например, по нажатию клавиши Escape закрывался виджет.

Comment: Какую имплементации imgui используете?

Comment: автор ocornut/imgui win 32 directx11

Answer (score 0):

В `header` игры, добавляете данный код: `std::unique_ptr<DirectX::Keyboard> m_keyboard;` далее в `*.cpp` файл игры, добавляете данный код в конец инициализаций `m_keyboard = std::make_unique<Keyboard>();` и там же, в TODO Update добавляете данный код:

```
auto kb = m_keyboard->GetState();
if ( kb.Escape )
{
    ImGui::End();
}
```

Comment: Или `const auto &kb`, чтобы не делать копию...

Comment: Я из ImGui нельзя получить состояние клавиш? там есть что то типа io.KeyDown[] и тд

Comment: Почему нельзя? Вы написали, что используете dx11, по этому я и написал совместимый код с этими двумя библитотеками, а так, можно и чисто ImGui. Убрать всё, что до этого было и использовать только `if` , с небольшими изменениями. Замените условие `kb.Escape`, на `ImGui::ImGuiKey_Escape`.